# React Router : Dynamically url id

Tags: reactjs

[image]

How can I implement dynamic paths when I click on a link like in a picture?

The user clicks on the link and goes to the message section, then clicks on the link (Link) and goes to the desired component.

**DATA:**

```
const data = [
    {
        link: 'Link Name 1',
        text: 'Text 1',
        id: '1'
    },
    {
        link: 'Link Name 2',
        text: 'Text 2',
        id: '2'
    },
    {
        link: 'Link Name 3',
        text: 'Text 3',
        id: '3'
    }
    ];
```

**App.js**

```
<Switch>
 <Route exact path="/" component={AppHome}/>
 <Route exact path="/messages" component={AppMessages}/>
 <Route exact path="/messages/chat" component={AppMessageItems}/>
 <Route exact path="/messages/chat/:id" component={AppMessageItems}/>
</Switch>
```

**Messages.js**

```
const AppMessages = () => {
             <ul>
                {data.map(function(item, index) {
                    return (
                        <li key={index}>
                            <Link to='/messages/chat'><AppMessageUserList {...item} /></Link>
                        </li>);
                })}
            </ul>
}
```

**AppMessageUserList**

```
const AppMessageUserList = ( props ) => {
const {link} = props;
   return ( <div> {link} </div> );

}
```

**AppMessageItems.js**

```
const AppMessageItems = () => {
   return ( <h1> Hello World </h1> );

}
```

But when i try this code i get error when click to link.

Comment: try to pass the id on AppMessageItems that will try to map in the exact page what you are looking for

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: @ionMobDev can you write code how i can do it ?

Comment: and whats in `AppMessageUserList `

Comment: @ZunaibImtiaz edit my post and add AppMessageUserList

Comment: @Bavarius Where are you getting `datas` in Messages.jsx from? Could you create a codesandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with

```js
// App.js
<Switch>
 <Route exact path="/" component={AppHome}/>
 <Route exact path="/messages" component={AppMessages}/>
 <Route path={["/messages/chat", "/messages/chat/:id"]} component={AppMessageItems}/>
</Switch>

// Messages.js
// Assuming item has id and upon clicking the item should change the url

const AppMessages = () => (
  <ul>
    {data.map((item, index) => 
      (
        <li key={item.id}>
          <Link to={`/messages/chat/${item.id}`}>
             <AppMessageUserList {...item} />
           </Link>
         </li>
       )
     }
    </ul>
)


// AppMessageItems

const AppMessageItems = (props) => {
if (props.match.params && props.match.params.id) {
   // return the selected items
 }
// return whatever you wanted to return if nothing is selected 
}
```

NOTE: Don't use index as key

Comment: Thanks for code, but when i use <Route path=["/messages/chat", "/messages/chat/:id"] component={AppMessageItems}/> 

terminal show error "Tag start is not closed"

Comment: you misplaced `[`, it should be

`<Route path=["/messages/chat", "/messages/chat/:id"] component={AppMessageItems}/>`

Comment: Yes, i'm using this way  <Route path=["/messages/chat", "/messages/chat/:id"] component={AppMessageItems}/> same with example, but "Tag start  is not closed"

Comment: I try path={["/messages/chat", "/messages/chat/:id"]} and works

Comment: Yea, I missed curly braces `{}` 

Comment: VIjan, thanks for code it's works. Then i have still one problem, how i can set data from my data to AppMessageItems component ?

Comment: if (props.match.params && props.match.params.id) { 
return ( <div> { text } </div> );
}

but give error AppMessageItems(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Comment: You should replace both return statement, inside and outside `if` block to your need. You skipped the return statement outside the if block. `return null` if you want nothing to render if there's no id

Comment: I try, but not works ( can you write code ? i update my data and add text key with value. can yu write code for little example ?